# Books like Silverman & Tate "Rational Points on Elliptic Curves"

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, elliptic-curves

I would appreciate mention of books similar to Silverman & Tate. Amongst features I find most appealing are:

-- it shows things I have studied (even marginally) in action, applied fairly extensively (around 250 pages) to one topic. Group theory, Galois theory, representation theory, cyclotomic fields, linear algebra. I find this very exciting and motivating to leave the realm of end-of-chapter problems and see applications of these topics.

-- particularly, as a self-studier, I find the text very accessible.

I would characterize my level (giving myself the benefit of the doubt) as advanced undergraduate.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want books just on elliptic curves, or on more general topics?

Comment: @GregoryGrant Any topic, including elliptic curves would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I think I understand the kind of writing you're looking for, having read Silverman & Tate.  Another author that brings things down to earth nicely like that is Edwards, I highly recommend his Galois Theory - he even takes the reader through Galois' original proof and makes you understand how Galois thought about it.